# ui-sref not adding href to html rendered and there by not clickable

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

No errors in console.

My code is simple and as below 
Home.html
    `<h2>Select the car for seeing details</h2>
    <div ui-view=""></div>`

    
        angular.module('cardealer', ['ngRoute', 'ui.router'])
        .controller('carcntrlr', function ($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location) {
            $scope.cars = [{ id: 1, name: 'Honda' }, { id: 2, name: 'Hyundai' }, { id: 3, name: 'Toyota' }];

```
    })
    .controller('cardetails',function($scope,$routeParams){

        $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
        $scope.name = $routeParams.name;
    })
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $routeProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/route")
        $stateProvider.state('cars', {
            url: "/route",
            templateUrl:'cars.html',
            controller: 'carcntrlr'
        })
          .state("cardetails", {
            url: '/car/:carId/:carName',
            templateUrl:'cardetails.html',
                controller:function($scope,$stateParams){

                    $scope.id = $stateParams.carId;
                    $scope.name = $stateParams.carName;
                }

        })
    })
    ;

</script>
```

Cars.html

```
<div>


<ul ng-repeat="car in cars">
    <li>
        <a ui-sref="carDetails({carId: '{{car.id}}',carName:'{{car.name}}'})">{{car.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<hr/>
<div ui-view></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While providing values to `ui-sref` state parameters, no need to use `{{}}` & `'`(single qoute) as well. Like you are passing value from scope variable here.

And next thing is typo in state name `carDetails` should be `cardetails`

```
ui-sref="cardetails({carId: car.id, carName: car.name})"
```

Comment: Thanks Pankaj.. though I was sure technically everything is correct. I was struggling to find out the issue here.

Comment: Just to clarify, issue is only with d and D, nothing to do with single quote(') and braces({{}}). Your approach and my approach both works.

Comment: @Raja4050 no, don't have `{{}}` interpolation inside expression again, it would mess

Answer (score 0):

First thing is what @Pankaj Parkar has pointed out so you should write

```
ui-sref="carDetails({carId: car.id, carName: car.name})"
```

Then in the states that you have defined the state name as carDetails (Note capital D) but
in your cars.html page you are calling state as cardetails(note small d)

same for the name of carDetails.html page